# How to create nginx ingress rules for services in 3 different namespaces in azure Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I have 3 services in 3 different namespaces I want my ingress rules to map to these backends, on path based routes.
Can someone please guide on the same.
I am using nginx ingress inside azure Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Have you tried to create `Ingress` resource **for each `namespace`** with the routes to the specific services?

Answer (score 1):

A basic example with an assumption that your `nginx ingress` is working correctly inside your `AKS` would be following:

List of `Pods` with their `Services`:

| Pod | Namespace | Service name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nginx | alpha | alpha-nginx |
| nginx | beta | beta-nginx |
| nginx | omega | omega-nginx |

---

`Ingress` definition for this particular setup:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: alpha-ingress
  namespace: alpha
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: "kubernetes.kruk.lan" 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /alpha(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: alpha-nginx
            port:
              number: 80
--- 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: beta-ingress
  namespace: beta
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: "kubernetes.kruk.lan" 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /beta(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: beta-nginx
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: omega-ingress
  namespace: omega
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: "kubernetes.kruk.lan" 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /omega(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: omega-nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

In this example `Ingress` will analyze and rewrite the requests for the **same domain name** to send the traffic to different namespaces i.e. `alpha`, `beta`, `omega`.

When you've have finalized your `Ingress` resource, you can use `curl` to validate your configuration.

```bash
curl kubernetes.kruk.lan/alpha | grep -i "<h1>"                                    
<h1>Welcome to nginx from ALPHA namespace!</h1>
```

```bash
curl kubernetes.kruk.lan/beta | grep -i "<h1>"                                    
<h1>Welcome to nginx from BETA namespace!</h1>
```

```bash
curl kubernetes.kruk.lan/omega | grep -i "<h1>"                                    
<h1>Welcome to nginx from OMEGA namespace!</h1>
```

I'd encourage you to check following docs on rewrites:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx: Examples: Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)*

---

PS: `Pods` are default `nginx` containers/images with added text to `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`

Comment: Will it work the same without host as well as I am using just in no host defined

Comment: @AbhishekSingh If you do not put `host` in the `Ingress` definition then your `Ingress` controller will "ignore" the `Host` header. Basically it will accept every request and push it to the relevant backend (according to the paths).